# RVM error when upgrading Ruby on Dreamhost VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I recently upgraded to a Dreamhost VPS and would like to install some RoR apps using Rails 4.2 and (preferably) Ruby 2.2. The server's default setup includes Ruby 1.8.7. Following thw wiki's instructions I used:

```
$RVM install 2.2.2
```

It fails due to (presumably) a missing path, ~/usr/local/sbin, according to the log. However the same error appears after creating the directory and re-running the RVM installation command.

Suggestions?

Comment: make sure rvm is up to date `rvm get stable`

Answer (score 0):

If you're literally typing:

`RVM install 2.2.2`

You should type:

`rvm install 2.2.2`

Case matters!